# How do you average repeating blocks of cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, range, average, offset

I am trying to figure out how to average 4 x 4 groups of cells in my spreadsheet across a very large data set. I've tried using OFFSET with a cell range (e.g. B2:E5) but I haven't had success (I don't even know if you can use a range for the reference with OFFSET). This is my first time tackling a problem like this, so any advice would be welcome! A portion of the data set is attached to give an idea of the ranges I would like to average.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify - in the example above, are you looking to get a 4x4 table of numbers, where each number is the average of 16 numbers in the corresponding area of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data was in B2:Q17 you could use this complicated looking formula to return the average for each 4*4 block.

```swift
=AVERAGE(INDEX($B$2:$Q$17,(ROWS($2:2)-1)*4+1,(COLUMNS($R:R)-1)*4+1):INDEX($B$2:$Q$17,(ROWS($2:2)-1)*4+4,(COLUMNS($R:R)-1)*4+4))
```

You would copy this across and down and it could go anywhere on a sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDEX` to refer to a range derived from values fro TopLeft and BottomRight corners, in the form

```
INDEX(DataRange, TopRow, LeftCol):INDEX(DataRange, BottomRow, RightCol)
```

Then wrap that in `AVERAGE(...)`

To demonstrate

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($B$7:$AH$903,B1,B2):INDEX($B$7:$AH$903,B3+B1-1,B4+B2-1))
```

[image]

Note: `INDEX` has the advantage over `OFFSET` in that it's [non-volatle](https://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm#:%7E:text=A%20Volatile%20Function%20is%20one,also%20contains%20non%2Dvolatile%20functions.)